# java object setter and creator in different switch cases

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm making a "monster creator" with a menu (switch)
1 - create empty monster
2 - create monster with parameters
3 - change/assign empty monster name
4 - ...
N - ...

When option 1 and 2 are already coded and they seem to work, the getters and the setters are tested and working in option 2.
Now, when I try to use the setter  for the empty monster Netbeans gives me a warning that the variable is not initialized, and when i run the code i get an error.

How can i fix this?

I'll try to add the code here so  it's more visual.

```
package Monstruo;

/**
 * @author JuanVictor
 */
public class ConfigMonstruo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int menu = 0, x, y;
        String monstruoVacio = "", monstruoConDatos = "", nombre, color;
        int opcion;
        int salida = 0;



        while (salida == 0) {

            ES.msg("Configuración de Monstruos.\n\n================================\n");
            ES.msgln("1.- Crear un nuevo monstruo sin datos.");
            ES.msgln("2.- Crear una nuevo monstruo con datos conocidos.");
            ES.msgln("3.- Asignar nombre a al monstruo sin datos.");
            ES.msgln("4.- Asignar posición X al monstruo sin datos.");
            ES.msgln("5.- Asignar posición Y al monstruo sin datos.");
            ES.msgln("6.- Asignar color al monstruo sin datos.");
            ES.msgln("7.- Mostrar por pantalla los datos de un monstruo.\n");
            ES.msgln("0.- Salir de la aplicación.\n================================");

            opcion = ES.leeEntero("Introduzca la opción elegida:  ", 0, 7);

            switch (opcion) {

                //opcion de salida del programa
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Aplicacion Finalizada");
                    salida = 1;
                    break;

                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Creando un nuevo monstruo sin datos...\n");
                    //un wait de 1 segundo con fines estéticos .
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);                 //1 segundo.
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                    //instanciación de el monstruo sin características
                    Monstruo mVacio = new Monstruo();

                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Creando un nuevo monstruo con datos conocidos...");
                    nombre = ES.leeCadena("Introduzca el nombre del monstruo: ");
                    x = ES.leeEntero("Introduzca la posicion X del monstruo: ");
                    y = ES.leeEntero("Introduzca la posicion Y del monstruo: ");
                    color = ES.leeCadena("Introduzca el color del monstruo: \n" );
                    Monstruo mDatos = new Monstruo(nombre, x, y, color);
                    mDatos.setNombre(nombre);
                    mDatos.setPosicionX(x);
                    mDatos.setPosicionY(y);
                    mDatos.setColor(color);
                    System.out.println("\n" +mDatos.toString()+"\n");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Asignar nombre a al monstruo sin datos.");
                    nombre=ES.leeCadena("Introdce el nombre del monstruo: ");

                    mVacio.setNombre(nombre); //here is the warning

                    break;

            }

        }
        //
    }
}
```

EDIT: the warning is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - variable mVacio might not have been initialized     at
>   Monstruo.ConfigMonstruo.main(ConfigMonstruo.java:73) Java Result: 1

Comment: Please add the error message and the stacktrace if your error is an exception.

Comment: Could you share the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: You need to provide a non 0 args constructor for your custom class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize `mVacio` only in `case 1` of the switch statement, it is only initialized when `case 1` is entered, so if `case 3` is entered before case 1, you try to access `mVacio` before it is initialized.

Therefore you should move the declaration of `mVacio` to be before the switch statement and give it an initial value :

```
Monstruo mVacio = null;
```

Then in case 1 you change :

```
Monstruo mVacio = new Monstruo();
```

to:

```
mVacio = new Monstruo();
```

And in case 3 :

```
if (mVacio != null)
    mVacio.setNombre(nombre);
```